# How to change color of subtext in the Text widget (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to change the color of specific text in the Text widget in Tkinter?

Any answer will be welcomed.

Comment: What research have you done? How to do this is well documented.

Comment: "Any answer will be welcomed." -I love this! Now tell me where's your code @Daniel? We are not fortune tellers here LOL!

Comment: Can you give me any specific documentation? I cant find it.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli I don't have any code because I don't have any idea of actually doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Library manual has a tkinter chapter that lists some online and paper materials.  I mostly use the [NMT reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html).  See its Text widget sections and in particular the [text methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html) section.

Tags are the specific answer to your question.  You can tag a slice of text with a string either when inserting or later (tag_add method). A slice can get multiple tags.  A tag can be applied to multiple slices.  One can customize 19 options for a given tag with the tag_config method.  Color is just one of them, but perhaps the most common.  It is used by syntax coloring.  Minimal example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert('insert', 'normal text')
text.insert('insert', ' red text', 'RED')
text.tag_config('RED', foreground='red')
root.mainloop()
```